# Joomla JError doesn't show but then appears

Tags: redirect, joomla

I have 3d party component which set JError warning

```
JError::raiseWarning( 99, "Set your name please" );
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect($r);
```

Redirect goes to controller with code

```
function saveUserDetails(){
//some code here

//now I try to get that error which was set by raiseWarning
$other_errors = JError::getErrors();
print_r($other_errors);
die;
```

It returns just empty array. Why It doesn't contain that error?

Ok, I try to check session var with Joomla messages

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$mes = $session->get('application.queue');
print_r($mes);
die;
```

Again empty. Where is that error, I can't understand.

Comment: If JError doesn't save this warning into some type of storage - session, database, etc - your warning will not persist into the next request. Consult the documentation to see if this scenario is even supported.

Comment: I mentioned two in my question I made two types of checking before posting question here. Check getErrors() and getSession() ways. I am not sure I check all types of storage. How can I check all types?

Answer (score 0):

If there is new request immediately after the redirect you might be loosing the session variable (JError content) inspect the fired requests with FireBug, Net tab, and see what happens there. Post any information you get there but if it's not in JErrors it shouldn't show on the site.

Can you give a link to the live site so I can test there and see the HTTP requests that could help.